# Class function called from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an Objective-C method like this:

```
-(void)findFiles{
}
```

It is working fine.But I need to call this method in Swift class.I have done :

```
var instanceOfCustomObject:DriveListTableViewController = DriveListTableViewController()
```

and now I can use the method like this:

```
instanceOfCustomObject.find()
```

But it works only in if I place it into viewDidLoad.
Is there a way that I can call it on click of button?
I have created button

```
let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 400, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

func buttonClicked() {
        print("Button Clicked")
        instanceOfCustomObject.findFiles()
        }
```

But it still works only if I place it into viewDidLoad. Please help me! Is there any other way to make it call in Swift file from Objective-C file??

Comment: What do you mean by "it only works..." - Clarify "works". You are creating an instance of `DriveListTableViewController` but apparently not presenting it in any way, so you are probably calling the method but it isn't having any result since the view controller isn't shown.

Comment: You can create an static utility with the method that you need, why are you instantiating a ViewController for just using a method ? You should only instantiate a View Controller if you intend to present it or display to the user.

Comment: @Paulw11I mean if I put "instanceOfCustomObject.find()" into viewDidLoad the function is called only once.But I need to call that function mutiple times with the button.How do I present it ? This is called in swift file. The -(void)findFiles{
} is located in Objective-C file... How do I call it else?

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani I am using instance of ViewController to access the function loacated n Objective C file,but I try to call it from swift file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `var instanceOfCustomObject` outside the `viewDidLoad` method (i.e., inside the class *but* outside the method).

Comment: @KirillMIlititskiy Ok, good! But is it `find()` or `findFiles()`?

Comment: Does it matter? Its the name. It could be any name.

Comment: @KirillMIlititskiy Yes, it can confuse future readers ;-) Pls fix this minor typo, thanks!